# Cant change webkit border-spacing

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, border-spacing

I've been working on some sort of a drawing grid recently and used border-spacing.

```
HTML:
<table id="table"></table>
    <script>
        var res = 16;
        var cell_size = 8;
        var table = document.getElementById("table");
        var border_size = parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(table).getPropertyValue("border-spacing"),10);

        table.style.width = (cell_size + border_size) * res + border_size + "px";
        table.style.height = (cell_size + border_size) * res + border_size + "px";

        for(y=0;y<res;y++){
            var row = table.insertRow();
            for(x=0;x<res;x++){
                row.insertCell();
            }
        }
    </script>


CSS:
table{
    background: #000000;
    border-spacing: 1px;
}
td{
    padding: 0;
    background: #c9c9c9;
}
```

Idea is to form a table with fixed amount of cells with  pre-set size and border spacing.

```
var res = 16;
var cell_size = 8;
var border_size = parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(table).getPropertyValue("border-spacing"),10);
```

Size of the whole table is then computed based on these parameters.

```
table.style.width = (cell_size + border_size) * res + border_size + "px";
table.style.height = (cell_size + border_size) * res + border_size + "px";
```

Finally the table is created via nested loop.

```
for(y=0;y<res;y++){
    var row = table.insertRow();
    for(x=0;x<res;x++){
        row.insertCell();
    }
}
```

If I use small (<4px) border size it doesn't seem to work right in Chrome - cell sizes start to be offset around 0.4 px. In Chrome there are 2 computed webkit options affecting this offset:

```
-webkit-border-horizontal-spacing
-webkit-border-vertical-spacing
```

However I can't change them like so:

```
-webkit-border-horizontal-spacing: 1px;
-webkit-border-vertical-spacing: 1px;
```

Computed values will  still stay at 0.8 px. It isn't much at the end, but it really bothers me. Is there any reason for such behaviour and is it possible to have exact cell sizes with such low values?

Here is an example fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/kdqoc4vy/1/

Note that cell_size should be **exactly** 20px, but in fact it is 19.2.

P.S. With Edge evertyhing works as it should. This 0.8px is almost nothing when the table is small, but when it has 64 rows and columns such inconsistency becomes a problem. Thanks in advance for your reply!